# How do I create a database entry with an intermediary table field in my serializer class?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Our project is a fictional webshop where you can put puppies in your cart and order them. The three main models that we have are Users, Orders and Puppies. Because every order has a list of puppies and every puppy has its own amount we needed an intermediary model for the two as a simple ManyToManyField apparently can't handle extra columns. This makes things much more complicated (at least for someone who is new to Django).
Also our authorization is via a JWT token, that's why the self.request.user apparently has to be manually set and isn't set automatically.
The only thing that should be possible to create via a POST are new orders. These should automatically get a date and the user posting it should also automatically be set. The total_price of an order should also be calculated so that the only things that need to be sent by the client are a list of puppies and their respective amounts.

POST in React:

```
async function createOrder(auth, puppies) {
  auth = auth.token
  puppies = puppies.map(element =>
    element = {'id' : element.puppy.id, 'amount': element.amount}
  )
  const res = await fetch(REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + `/shop/orders/`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "JWT " +  auth
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ puppies })
    })
  return res.json()
```

**console.log results in: [{"id":2,"amount":1},{"id":3,"amount":1}]**

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Puppy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    weight = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    description_de = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    description_en = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Order(models.Model):
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    puppies = models.ManyToManyField(Puppy, through='PuppyOrder')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='orders')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class PuppyOrder(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    puppy = models.ForeignKey(Puppy, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_address(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Address.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_address(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.address.save()
```

views.py:

```
from shop.models import Puppy, Order
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import permissions, status, viewsets, generics
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
from rest_framework_jwt.serializers import VerifyJSONWebTokenSerializer
from .serializers import UserSerializer, UserSerializerWithToken, OrderSerializer, PuppySerializer
from .permissions import IsOwner


@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'users': reverse('user-list', request=request, format=format),
        'orders': reverse('order-list', request=request, format=format),
        'puppies': reverse('puppy-list', request=request, format=format),
    })


class OrderList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Order.objects.all().filter(user=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        print('Creating new order...')
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)


class OrderDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Order.objects.all().filter(user=self.request.user)


class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all().select_related('address')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all().select_related('address')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class PuppyList(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    queryset = Puppy.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PuppySerializer


class PuppyDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    queryset = Puppy.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PuppySerializer
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from .models import Order, Puppy, PuppyOrder


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orders = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'orders')


class UserSerializerWithToken(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Code to generate token on login ...

class PuppySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    description = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_description(self, puppy):
        return {'DE': puppy.description_de, 'EN': puppy.description_en}

    class Meta:
        model = Puppy
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'price', 'image_url', 'age', 'weight', 'description')


class PuppyOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    puppy = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='puppy.id')
    order = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='order.id')

    class Meta:
        model = PuppyOrder
        fields = ('order', 'puppy', 'amount')


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
    puppies = PuppyOrderSerializer(source='puppyorder_set', many=True)

        def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
        puppies = validated_data.pop("puppyorder_set")
        order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        total_price = 0
        for puppy in puppies:
            puppy_id = puppy.get("id")
            amount = puppy.get("amount")
            puppy_instance = Puppy.objects.get(pk=puppy_id)
            total_price += puppy_instance.price
            PuppyOrder(order=order, puppy=puppy_instance, amount=amount).save()
        order.save()
        return Order

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('id', 'total_price', 'puppies', 'date', 'user')
```

This code results in an error: "*Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use puppies.set() instead.*"
Please tell me what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things you're not getting quite right. First, the authentication. Please checkout [DRF-JWT](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt) or similar libraries and use their authentication classes or atleast see how to create yours so that you don't have your authentication littered all over your code.

As for the `perform_create` in your view, you don't really have to check `serializer.is_valid()` there. It is already checked in `create` before `perform_create` is called. And that method is not meant to return  an API response as far as I know. It's just meant to perform any other extra actions you want before calling `serializer.save()`. For most basic usages, it is never overriden. You can also pass in your user and the date there to the save method or do that in the serializer.

Now, in the serializer's create method, you do not need to access `initial_data`. All you need should be in `validated_data`. First, you should pop the `puppies` from `validated_data` before calling `objects.create`, else, it wouldn't be able to handle it. Then you can now create the `PuppyOrder` objects using the earlier on popped puppies.

This is how you add extra data to the serializer's validated_data in the view's perform_create:

```
serializer.save(date=datetime.today(), user=self.request.user, total_price=total_price)
```

You can do the same in the serializer's create method by just addind the items directly in the validated data. It's just a normal dictionary afterall:

```
validated_data['user'] = self.context['request'].user
validated_data['date'] = datetime.today()
validated_data['total_price'] = total_price
```

**EDIT: Using a non model serializer for PuppyOrder**

Since the order and PuppyOrder is not yet created at the time the request is being sent, the following line in the OrderSerializer would result to an error because the the serializer expects actual PuppyOrders

```
puppies = PuppyOrderSerializer(source='puppyorder_set', many=True)
```

Instead you can use non model serializer like this(assuming the puppy already exists):

```
class PuppyOrderCreateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    puppy = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Puppy.objects.all())
    amount = serializers.IntegerField()
```

Then you can use this serializer in yuur OrderSerializer:

```
puppies_data = PuppyOrderCreateSerializer(many=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! I checked out the JWT docs again. Because I was using "Bearer" instead of "JWT" in the authorization header my self.request.user was never set which lead to that authorization mess which you can see in my code. It's all muuch clearer now, thank you! I'll edit my question with the changes.
As for the second part I removed the validation part and the 400 response. (Responses are probably sent automatically if something goes wrong, right?)
3: validated_data only contains {'puppies': [{'amount': 1, 'id': 2}, {'amount': 1, 'id': 3}]}
for me...

Comment: I still don't quite understand your third point. My validated_data only contains *{'puppies': [{'amount': 1, 'id': 2}, {'amount': 1, 'id': 3}]}* for me. Is it a problem that the user field is declared as a ReadOnlyField? Or does that only mean that "user" is not a necessary field that needs to get sent via POST?

Comment: If you open the `CreateModelMixin` where `perform_create` is inherited from, you will see that it doesn't actually return anything. The `create` method returns the response while `perform_create` is just meant for extra stuff. I will advise that you regularly check the source code as it really helps understand the framework better. I do that a lot.

Comment: You cannot pass `puppies` to Order's create method because it is not a field, it is rather a manager. So like I already explained, add user, total_price and date to validated_data but pop out puppies before calling the objects.create. As for the user, you can make it readonly if it should be got from the request. It is not necessary to add it to POST data

Comment: Good tip, I'll try reading the source code more, thanks! How would I add something to validated_data? Do I add it as a parameter to the create method in the view? 
The date should actually be automatically set to the current time when the order is saved in the model, so I can probably make it readonly, too right? As for the total_price, this should be calculated while saving and not sent via post.

Comment: Yes, you can add it in the view or serializer. Check my update. You can make them read_only

Comment: I added user=self.request.user to the save function in the view and formed the code like you said. The strange thing now is that my validated_data now looks like this: *{'user': <User: Customer_1>, 'puppyorder_set': [OrderedDict([('amount', 1)]), OrderedDict([('amount', 1)])]}
[OrderedDict([('amount', 1)]), OrderedDict([('amount', 1)])]*
I'll edit my post with the newest changes. The error I'm getting now is: *shop.models.DoesNotExist: Puppy matching query does not exist.
*

Comment: Because it tries to fetch the `PuppyOrder`s from the data given. I would remove this line `puppies = PuppyOrderSerializer(source='puppyorder_set', many=True)` because you can't send a valid PuppyOrder when the order doesn't yet exist. Instead, make another serializer(not a model serializer) that contains a puppy and amount. You can then use that serializer in your order serializer

Comment: Makes sense, but doesn't that mean I'd have to change the model too and remove the manyToManyField for puppies? Also, could I just use a normal Serializer for the PuppyOrderSerializer then and call PuppyOrder(...).save() with the same data? And would I have to change the fields in the PuppyOrderSerializer to something else than ReadOnlyField? (Thank you so much btw, I feel like it's almost working)

Comment: You don't have to touch the model. Just use a normal serializer which isn't a model serializer. Check my update. make sure to send id's of puppies that actually exist

Comment: That's it, thank you so much for your help! You literally saved my weekend! One last thing: because orders are getting created before I loop through and create the puppies I don't have the total_price at the time of creation. Is there a smart way to either calculate it before creating the order or just updating it afterwards? 
*Order.objects.save(order, total_price=total_price)* is not working.

Comment: I didn't know how you calculate total price when I added that line. Of course, you can calculate it from the data before creating, but it makes sense to update it afterwards. Generally, such fields are not very good as they can be easily calculated instead of saved. Each time you add a new puppy order or update one, you would have to recalculate and save it. If all the puppy orders for a particular order are only created once, then it does make sense to store it, if not, just remove the field and add a property that calculates it when needed.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but if I fetch my orders now it won't fetch the puppies and their amounts for an order anymore. Is there an easy solution to this or should I post a new question for it?

Comment: If you named that field `puppies_data` as I suggested, then just add `puppies` to serializer meta's fields and also add it to the meta's read_only fields

Comment: You're a genius! I guess that should be all then, can't thank you enough!

Comment: I would love to but sadly I don't have 15 reputation yet, which is needed for upvoting things. I'll try and remember to do it later!

Comment: It's Ok. That will do